# Call Method of Child Web Component

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm really having difficulty trying to figure out how to call a function of a nested Polymer web component.

Here's the markup:

```
<rise-playlist>
  <rise-playlist-item duration="5">
     <rise-distribution distribution='[{"id":"VGZUDDWYAZHY"}]'></rise-distribution>
  </rise-playlist-item>
</rise-playlist>
```

The `rise-distribution` component has a `canPlay` function that I would like to call from inside of `rise-playlist`.

The `dom-module` definition of `rise-playlist` looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="rise-playlist">
  <template>
    <content id="items" select="rise-playlist-item"></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

I can successfully access the `rise-distribution` element like this:

```
var distribution = Polymer.dom(this.$.items[0]).querySelector("rise-distribution");
```

However, when I try to call `distribution.canPlay()`, it says that `distribution.canPlay` is not a function.

I've defined the `dom-module` of `rise-playlist-item` like this:

```
<dom-module id="rise-playlist-item">
  <content id="dist" select="rise-distribution"></content>
</dom-module>
```

Not sure if I need that `<content>` tag, although neither works.

Any ideas?

Thx.

Comment: In theory your code *should* work as you've described it. Polymer component methods are attached directly to the HTMLElement, so they're available everywhere no matter how you access the element.  Can you provide a jsbin or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I know that there have been a while but I am sure this problems still occurs as it is being viewed number of times.

Probably there is a problem with your component definition. Let me explain.
This is the way you put your child component inside DOM:

```
<your-child-component></your-child-component>
```

And and this should be the definition of your component:

```
Polymer({

  is: 'your-child-component',

  apiMethod: function() {
  //some stuff
  }
});
```

If you by mistake or due copy-paste error mistype the `is: 'your-child-component'` part, so it will not reflect the `<your-child-component>` you will get confused becouse your:

```
this.$$('your-child-component').apiMethod();
```

will tell you that there is no method you are willing to call.

Polymer correctly identified and selected from DOM `<your-child-component>` but if you have different `is` property (like for example `is: your_child_component>`) it will not attach its API to dom element you selected.

I hope that it will help if anyone ever will encounter this problem.